# The unpredictable loading bar -- or, the slot machine effect

Tags: perception, time

Say we A-B tested user reactions to completing some task (e.g. transferring files, restarting their device): would people be quicker to get impatient/ annoyed if they got random percentages as indicators of progress, or if they had a steady, accurate progress bar? What if it was steady but NOT accurate?
When would people experience the most intense emotional drops or rises? Would the slot machine effect play a part, i.e. would the chance of getting a "big" leap (21% towards update installation!) keep users waiting patiently during the slower progress intervals?

This question is based off a wandering thought while my laptop was restarting recently, as well as some basic psych understanding. I can certainly see it being possible that people would, on average, be more willing to wait for a 2/3/8 min update with erratic progress than 1/2/5 mins with steady progress.
I'd be interested if anyone knows of such/similar studies and, if so, what conclusions they reached.

Edit: internet legend Tom Scott came through and discussed this topic recently, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iZnLZFRylbs!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of studies ([Harrison et al, 2007](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1294211.1294231); [Amer & Johnson, 2016](https://doi.org/10.4018/IJTHI.2016100101)) tested pauses/stalls in progress, and concluded (respectively): "... participants perceived progress bars with pauses as taking longer to complete ..." and "... participants preferred a progress bar that moves consistently to a stalling progress bar, and judged the process duration to be shorter ..." suggesting that continuous/steady progress bars are preferred by users over intermittent/random indicators.

There is much more research on continuous progress indicators (eg, [Villar, Callegaro, & Yang, 2013](https://doi.org/10.1177%2F0894439313497468); [Liu & Wronski, 2018](https://doi.org/10.1177/0894439317695581)) that suggests that users generally prefer fast-to-slow / decelerating progress - that is, inaccurate progress bars that overestimate progress early on.  Slot machines similarly use early success to increase player perseverance, a kind of [anchoring bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchoring_(cognitive_bias)).  However, most of this research is on progress indicators for active tasks such as filling out surveys.  Some experiments with passive waiting (like file transfers) align with their results (eg, [Gronier & Baudet, 2019](https://www.doi.org/10.17140/PCSOJ-5-144); [Kuroki & Ishihara, 2015](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-21383-5_113)), but other studies show a preference for accelerating progress instead (eg, [Harrison et al, 2007](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1294211.1294231)), so I would wait for a meta-analysis specific to passive tasks before making a firm conclusion.

There are also various exploratory studies testing alternative progress bar displays, such as different [colours](https://doi.org/10.1109/INCoS.2011.65) and [shapes](https://doi.org/10.1109/INCoS.2014.85), [designs](https://doi.org/10.1145/1753326.1753556) and [animations](https://doi.org/10.1145/2851581.2892308), adding [audio](https://www.doi.org/10.14236/ewic/AD1998.9) and [video](https://doi.org/10.4018/ijthi.2014070105), suggesting that user perceptions can be altered in a variety of novel ways.  As well, progress indicators on passive tasks may be affected by the [labour illusion](https://doi.org/10.1109/INCoS.2014.85), in which user experience is influenced by the perceived amount of work done.

Comment: is this a kind of lying? What are some ethic aspect of this?

Comment: @Ooker You may be interested in [this article](https://www.process.st/loading-time/) - there is much worse going on with progress bars, and it's all done because users prefer it that way!